# How Do I return a variable that is changed within a function inside a class and use it in a function outside of the class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use a button (tkinter) to try and change the difficulty of my game. When I click either the easy, medium or hard button it should change the overall difficulty to the corresponding values of each difficulty 12,16,20 respectively. However, when I try and use the changed difficulty value outside of the class I get an error:
screen.ontimer(play, 1000 // difficulty)
NameError: name 'difficulty' is not defined

I have tried to return self.difficulty but I am not sure on how to do it.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.difficulty = -1

        self.grid()
        self.login = self.create_main()
        self.read = None

    def changeVariable1(self):
        self.difficulty = 12

    def changeVariable2(self):
        self.difficulty = 16

    def changeVariable3(self):
        self.difficulty = 20


    def diff(self):
        global radius
        if self.difficulty == 12:
            radius = (30)
        elif self.difficulty == 16:
            radius = (20)
        elif self.difficulty == 20:
            radius = (10)



    def create_read(self):
        read = Toplevel()
        Button(read, text="Easy", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable1).grid(row=3, column=2)
        Button(read, text="Medium", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable2).grid(row=3, column=3)
        Button(read, text="Hard", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable3).grid(row=3, column=4)

        return read

def play(app):
    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    timeTaken = time() - startTime

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))

    screen.title('SCORE: {}, TIME LEFT: {}'.format(score, int(round(gameLength - timeTaken, 0))))

    if time() - startTime > gameLength:
        screen.title('FINAL SCORE: {}'.format(score))
        screen.onclick(None)
        screen.clear()
    else:
        screen.ontimer(play, 1000 // app.difficulty)



root = Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()

play(app)
```

I expect the chosen value of difficulty (through the button) to be used in the function play().

Comment: You can refer to `app.difficulty` within `play`.  You should pass `app` as an argument to `play` rather than accessing it as a global.

Answer (score 0):

your function is outside the class so if you want to use any member of the class then you should pass the object of the class as the argument in your outside function and threw that object you can use that member of the class.

so please check the updated code given below..

```
def play(app):
    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    timeTaken = time() - startTime

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))

    screen.title('SCORE: {}, TIME LEFT: {}'.format(score, int(round(gameLength - timeTaken, 0))))

    if time() - startTime > gameLength:
        screen.title('FINAL SCORE: {}'.format(score))
        screen.onclick(None)
        screen.clear()
    else:
        screen.ontimer(play, 1000 // app.difficulty)



root = Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()

play(app)
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me the error: TypeError: play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'

Comment: please, edit your question's code with your edited code which i suggested so i can more help you with your updated error.

Comment: can i know that what is the work of TK() and mainloop(). ??

Comment: to keep the window open

Comment: Python idle 3.0 I think